# 3G USB modem support with TP-LINK MR3020

Tags: router, wireless-router, 3g

I am planning to purchase TP-LINK MR3020 3G/4G Wi-Fi router to use it with my Huawei E1550 3G USB Stick. But the problem is my usb stick is not present in the compatibility list of this router [here](http://www.tp-link.com/en/support/3g-comp-list/?model=TL-MR3020&location=1151).

So my questions are, is it the final list? & no other USB stick other than these will work with this router? Or is it not? what i mean is if anyone out there using the same set of devices that i've mentioned here and it is working for him/her or i've to go for another router or USB stick? Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It would have been better to find something compatible with your USB before buying something you were unsure would be...? Have you tried connecting the USB to see if it works?

Comment: 1. i think you are right. 2. No i dont have one to try.

Comment: Please accept my apologies, kunal, I forgot you'd written that you were "planning on buying"... ok, you may want to find something that definitely has your modem on a list of compatible devices. Although it may work, is it worth the risk of it arrives and doesn't work?

Comment: You are right, i've found the alternate router that supports the USB dongle i have. Thanks a lot.